# Python 3.3 и PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: python, postgresql

Не получается связать вместе Python 3.3 и PostgreSQL 9.2 (система Windows 7 x64). Скачал для связи pg-python, но он не инсталлируется, только когда в командной строке питона набираю "import postgresql" - все работает, база создана, таблица в ней, запросы работают, а из скрипта запускать это дело не получается, выдается ошибка "чё это такое за модуль postgresql"...

PostgreSQL 9.2 настроен и работает на localhost на порту 5432

Пожалуйста, не предлагайте psycopg2 - он написано только для питона 3.2. Если у вас есть версия для питона 3.3, то предлагайте и напишите откуда его можно скачать :)

Comment: а если полный путь до модуля указать?

Comment: Может, надо при запуске как-то модифицировать PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! К сожалению, ни один не подошёл... Разработкой займусь на домашнем макинтоше, там всё хорошо работает без лишних костылей...